# Scheme: Mapping a list as argument to a function

Tags: list, recursion, functional-programming, scheme, lisp

If I have a function that takes 3 arguments, and returns a list:

```
(some-function 1 2 3) --> '(3 2 1)
```

and I have a list of lists like this:

```
( (1 2 3) (2 1 3) (3 2 1) )
```

How can I map "some-function" to use all the lists as elements?

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the lists are only nested once then it is possible to turn them into a single list using `fold` and `append` and call `some-function` on the result with `apply` i.e

```
(fold append '() '((1 2 3) (2 1 3) (3 2 1))) => (2 3 1 3 2 1 1 2 3)
(apply some-function (2 3 1 3 2 1 1 2 3))
```

Otherwise you can just wrap `apply` and the `some-function` in a lambda you pass to `map`

```
(map (lambda (x) (apply some-function x)) '((1 2 3) (2 1 3) (3 2 1)))
```

Comment: Sorry, I'm new to this language. I tried to use the map function, not knowing the apply function existed. 
Thanks for the answer, it helped alot!

Answer (score 2):

I am not sure what result you mean.

```
(define (rev-list a b c)
  (list c b a))

(rev-list 1 2 3)
⇒ (3 2 1)

(apply rev-list '((1 2 3) (2 1 3) (3 2 1)))
⇒ ((3 2 1) (2 1 3) (1 2 3))

(map (lambda (l) (apply rev-list l)) '((1 2 3) (2 1 3) (3 2 1)))
⇒ ((3 2 1) (3 1 2) (1 2 3))
```

Comment: Sorry, I'm new to this language. I tried to use the map function, not knowing the apply function existed. 
Thanks for the answer, it helped alot!